# Class Design w/ Generics

Tags: c#, oop, generics, interface, abstract

I've recently gotten more involved in class design. I am having trouble coming up with a good class design for the following scenario.

I have a generic, abstract base class which, for simplicity's sake, looks like this:

```
public abstract class ElementDataService<T> where T : Element
{       
    public abstract void InsertElement(T element);
    public abstract void UpdateElement(ElementKey key, T element);
    public abstract void DeleteElement(ElementKey key);
}
```

I then have 4 child classes that inherit from it. E.g.:

```
public class PointElementDataService : ElementDataService<PointElement>
{        
    public override void InsertElement(PointElement point)
    {

    }

    public override void UpdateElement(ElementKey key, PointElement point)
    {

    }

    public override void DeleteElement(ElementKey key)
    {

    }
}
```

I'd like to implement a factory class to create one of the 4 sub-classes but there don't seem to be any return types to be able to achieve that.

I guess I'd like to house any one of the 4 sub-classes in one object type so that I can call insert/update/delete without needing to know which of the 4 types it is.

E.g.

```
public class ElementDataServiceFactory
{
    public static ElementDataService<Element> CreateElementDataService(ElementType type)
    {
        ElementDataService<Element> service = null;

        switch (type)
        {
            case ElementType.Base:
                service = BaseElementDataService.CreateBaseElementDataService();
                break;
            case ElementType.Section:
                service = SectionElementDataService.CreateSectionElementDataService();
                break;
            case ElementType.Point:
                service = PointElementDataService.CreatePointElementDataService();
                break;
            case ElementType.Other:
                service = OtherElementDataService.CreateOtherElementDataService();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return service;
    }
}
```

Obviously the above doesn't work due to casting issues, nor does anything else I've tried (e.g. generic factory method).

Comment: What about `public static ElementDataService<T> 
 CreateElementDataService()  where T : Element`?

Comment: I tried that as well, but I had the same casting issue as I did in the above example. It didn't seem to complain if I did this:

    'BaseElementDataService.CreateBaseElementDataService() as ElementDataService<T>;'

But I didn't try running it so I'm not even sure if that would work. It also seemed kind of weird to have to cast it like that so I didn't pursue it any further..

Comment: I understand that you would need to generate one of the classes based on some conditions? Or just the type name passed to it?

Comment: Does 'PointElement' derive from 'Element'?

Comment: @crazyGamer Just the type

Comment: @J.D. Yes it does

Comment: Please, provide real scenario of work. Now it's  unclear what do you need and why. For example, if you want store any class - it's one solution, if you need to store specific type - it's another (i.e. generic factory)

Comment: Are you doing this solely for the purpose of being able to call InsertElement, UpdateElement, DeleteElement with the different types of elements?

Comment: And their is no magical way for easy switching between strong types and duck-type. Somewhere you need to specific type and main question is in which  way you do that.

Comment: Why abstract class? Why not interface with invariant parameter?

Answer (score 0):

`ElementDataService<PointElement>, ElementDataService<BaseElement>` et al cannot be cast to ElementDataService.

```
public class PointElementDataService : ElementDataService<Element>
        {
            public override void InsertElement(Element point) { }
            public override void UpdateElement(ElementKey key, Element point) { }
            public override void DeleteElement(ElementKey key) { }

            public static ElementDataService<Element> CreatePointElementDataService()
            {
                return new PointElementDataService();
            }
        }
```

Comment: It wouldn't always be a PointElement though. It could be any one of: ElementDataService<SectionElement>, ElementDataService<BaseElement>, or ElementDataService<OtherElement> as well.

Comment: I edited my answer above. The above definition resolves the casting errors. You will still be able to pass a PointElement (or BaseElement/OtherElement/SectionElement) into each of your methods. e.g. `service.InsertElement(new PointElement());`